# upload files from arrays uisng multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

formData payload:-

```
education[0][university]: 
jru
education[0][degree]: 
mca
education[0][specialization]: 
computer application
education[0][certificate_pdf_url]: 
(binary)
education[0][degree_type]: 
Teaching Degree
education[0][years_of_study]: 
["2021-12-31T18:30:00.000Z","2026-12-31T18:30:00.000Z"]
```

Question:  How to upload files of formdata of arrays using multer in express js. here i have file in education[0].certificate_pdf_url , like that it can be education[0,1,2...].certificate_pdf_url. so how i can upload to multer either using fields or array?

```js
  "/save-education-details",
  authenticate,
  upload.array("education.certificate_pdf_url"),
  tutorController.saveEducationDetails
);
```

I am trying to upload one by one certificate_pdf_url file form the formData array.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Multer's `any()` method instead, so you have to worry about the field name:

```
upload.any(),
```